# Even after Changing the rules of firebase I am unable to access the data nodes which are open to all user autenticated and not autenticated too?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

This are my firebase rules

My Firebase Rules :

```
{
      "rules": {
          "ingredients": {
            ".read": "true",
            ".write": "true"
          },
          "orders": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
              ".indexOn":["userId"]
          }
      }
}
```

Error : 
    Permission denied even when accesing node ingredient

Code :

```
export const initIngredients = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get('/ingredients .json').then(response => {
            dispatch(setIngredients(response.data));
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchIngredientsFailed());
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to read/write.

Comment: export const initIngredients = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get( '/ingredients .json' )
            .then( response => {
               dispatch(setIngredients(response.data));
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                dispatch(fetchIngredientsFailed());
            } );
    };
};

Comment: Please use the [edit] button below your question to include this information.

Comment: Have you tried using the actual boolean `true` instead of the string `"true"`?

Comment: yes @GabrielLovetro it didn't work and produced the same error

Comment: Thanks For help . 
I achieved my required solution.
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
    "orders":{
       ".read":"auth != null",
          
        ".write":"auth !=null",
        ".indexOn":["userId"]
    }
  }
}